# Formula field used to check if info on related object is being completed

Tags: formula-field

I have the following formula field in a custom object, which is being used to tell me if the address in the related object is being populated. It stopped working. Its supposed to be unchecked if the address is not populated. Any idea?

```
OR( 
NOT(ISBLANK(Account_LC__r.HQ_City__c)), 
NOT(ISBLANK(Account_LC__r.HQ_Country__c)), 
NOT(ISBLANK(Account_LC__r.HQ_State_Province__c)), 
NOT(ISBLANK(Account_LC__r.HQ_Street__c)), 
NOT(ISBLANK(Account_LC__r.HQ_Zip_Postal_Code__c)), 
NOT(ISBLANK(Account_LC__r.Company_Legal_Name__c)) 
)
```

Comment: Why not set up a validation rule (on `Account_LC__c`) to ensure that this information is populated? Writing a formula to notify you about this on a child object seems like a really weak and roundabout way to enforce this.

Comment: Also, as usual, providing an example of what "not working" really helps. What input are you seeing that causes the wrong output? and what is the wrong output? The way this formula is structured right now, it seems to me like your checkbox would be checked if _any_ of those fields aren't blank (instead of if _all_ of those fields aren't blank). Are you sure that's what you intended?

Comment: Its a formula field using a checkbox. It works or it doesn't. Wasn't sure if it wasn't working due to a problem in the conditions. It was a Salesforce problem. Salesforce support was able to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula works fine. This was a problem with Salesforce. Salesforce Support was able to fix this issue internally.